# problem with making edittext scrollable

Tags: android, scroll, android-edittext

i am using an edittext in my application.this is set as focusable=false.but i want to make it automatically scrollabe when a big value is displaying..plz help me.given below is my code snippett

```
 <EditText android:text="" 
    android:hint="0"
    android:textColor="#3232CC"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:focusable="false"
   android:layout_marginLeft="45dip"
    android:editable="false"
     android:textSize="14dip"
   android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/netreturn"
   android:layout_below="@+id/totalinvestvalue"
    android:id="@+id/netreturnvalue" 
    android:layout_width="150dip" 
    android:layout_height="40dip" 
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:gravity="right" 
    android:isScrollContainer="true" 
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"></EditText>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `android:singleLine="true"` and you will be able to scroll horizontally.