# Android Auto Scrolling EditText Hint

Tags: android, android-edittext

[problem with making edittext scrollable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6250041/problem-with-making-edittext-scrollable)

there is mentioned that it is not scrollable with singleLine=true.

So i have 2 options:

1. I check if the user inputs "\n" and delete that, then i have to worry about things in the second line, too.
2. I use a custom textviews which scrolls through in a loop, could this be used here too only for the hint ?

   ```
    <com.test.ScrollingTextView
           android:id="@+id/textView1"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent"
           android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
           android:layout_weight="0.17"
           android:background="@color/black"
           android:ellipsize="marquee"
           android:gravity="center_vertical"
           android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
           android:paddingLeft="10dp"
           android:scrollHorizontally="true"
           android:singleLine="true"
           android:text="@string/editLength"
           android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
           android:textColor="@color/white" />
   ```

public class ScrollingTextView extends TextView {

```
public ScrollingTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

public ScrollingTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public ScrollingTextView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

@Override
protected void onFocusChanged(boolean focused, int direction, Rect previouslyFocusedRect) {
    if (focused)
        super.onFocusChanged(focused, direction, previouslyFocusedRect);
}

@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean focused) {
    if (focused)
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(focused);
}

@Override
public boolean isFocused() {
    return true;
}
```

}

I just cant get this formated right. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your EditText Scrollable like this:

```
EditText yourEditText = new EditText(context);
yourEditText.setScroller(new Scroller(context)); 
yourEditText.setMaxLines(1); 
yourEditText.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true); 
yourEditText.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

Comment: yourEditText.setMaxLines(1); doesnt seem to work, gets split into 2 lines

Comment: are you looking to scroll horizontally ?

Comment: I actually dont want to scroll it, id rather let it scroll automatically, like with the TextView i posted above.

Comment: The answer does not help for auto scrolling the hint