# EditText hint automatic horizontal scroll (marquee)

Tags: android, scroll, android-edittext, marquee

I am using EditText which is of single line. However, the hint of the EditText is larger than the size of EditText layout. I want the hint to horizontal scroll automatically (with or without focus) something similar to marquee. I don't want horizontal ScrollView either. This then has to be manually scrolled. Would it be possible to horizontal scroll it automatically till the end of hint and back.

Something like this, but for android!
Thanks

```
<marquee>This is basic example of marquee</marquee>
```

P.S This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11373774/8949762) isn't working for me.

Providing `android:ellipsize="marquee"` and
    `android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"`
gives me EditText inflator error

My EditText code is as follows -

```
<EditText                               
android:id="@+id/schedule_location_city"                 
style="@style/Mystyle_EditText"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:layout_weight="0.60"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:hint="Choose Location on Map"
android:isScrollContainer="true" />
```

Comment: Add these two properties to your textView , android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"

Comment: and dont forget to do textView.setSelected(true) in the oncreate(), that will make it running..

Comment: I want it on hint of EditText and not on TextView; and this is not working on TextView either.

Comment: added ans for review in the post.